# Should bcrypted passwords be stored as byte array or as string and why?

Tags: encoding, passwords, bcrypt

I read on some SO answer (which I can't seem to find again) that bcrypted passwords must be stored as byte array in the database. I'm storing them as string. Is there any advantage I gain by storing them as byte array or maybe it's more secure that way?

Comment: When you say you are storing the passwords, I hope you are speaking in shorthand. Decrypting what you store should not reveal anyone's password. See this [Dev FAQ](http://plaintextoffenders.com/faq/devs).

Comment: The output of many BCrypt implementations is a string, so it is clearly wrong to say, that the hash must be stored as byte array.

Comment: @TomBlodget I'm storing bcrypted password as string. I'm converting the byte array from bcrypt to hex string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing a base64 string?  That's exactly as secure as raw binary.  Treating raw binary as an ASCII string?  That might get messed up during read, write, string processing, table export/backup.  For example binary 0 = \0 = end of string marker in many languages.

Answer (score 2):

An encoding doesn't change the security of the system. Use whatever is easier and compatible with your database. As always the encoding that you choose and the database API must be appropriate for arbitrary binary data, most character encodings such as UTF-8 and ASCII are not.